# finding the supremum

Tags: calculus, proof-verification, supremum-and-infimum

> Let $A=\{x:\frac{[b\cdot n]}{n}\}$ when $n\in \mathbb{N}$ find the supremum

we know that $b\cdot n-1<[b\cdot n]<b \cdot n$ therefore $b- \frac{1}{n}<\frac{[b\cdot n]}{n}<b$ so b is a upper bound.

Let Assume that there is $M<b$ so that M is the supremum.
So $\frac{[b\cdot n]}{n}<M$ but we know that $\frac{[b\cdot n]}{n}<\frac{b \cdot n}{n}=b$ so we have $\frac{[b\cdot n]}{n}<\frac{b \cdot n}{n}=b<M$ contradiction.

Is the proof valid?

Comment: No. There's something with the last step.

Comment: @BolzWeir What do you think is the problem?

Comment: The problem is that although $\frac{[bn]}{n}$ is bounded by $bn/n$, i.e. $b$, that doesn't tell us that $b<M$. We know that $M$ is the supremum, so it's the *least* upper bound. So, the conclusion should be $\ldots = b \ge M$. Which doesn't tell us something new. As for how to solve this, we know that the sequence converges to $b$ using the first inequality. If we can show that the sequence is nondecreasing, then we are done.